# Anyone know of a good way to sell used servers?

Tags: reseller

We have a couple of servers we no longer need now that we are fully hosted on a managed host (rackspace). They were purchased for over $10,000 each but we realize that over time their monetary value drops. Anyone have suggestions or experience selling these in a proper way? They are dual xeon processor 2U rack mountable with 4+GB RAM, intel boards, 6x 72GB 15,000 RPM SCSI Drives with raid controller redundant power supply. We are in Southern California area. I can be more specific on any information if there is interest. I know there is ebay and the like but these servers are like the family dog that has to be given up and we are looking for a proper home for a fair price. I will end up auctioning it off if need be in the end though. Thanks in advanced for any help!

Comment: Consider donating them to an educational institution and taking a writeoff.

Comment: Just as an additional hint: Make sure that you properly wipe the data of your hard drive, unless you want to have the buyer recover it and post it on the internet.

Comment: They might have cost a lot when you bought them; but around here something like that would go for about $100 each. Brand new servers with 3 year warranties that are more powerful than those only cost ~$1500; putting a warranty on those would cost 2 or 3 times that (if you can still buy extended warranties for that hardware).

Comment: "these servers are like the family dog"... even Ol' Yeller got put down.  Consider developing a realistic depreciation schedule for your hardware, EX: over five years value of the kit drops to zero.

Comment: "15000 RPM SCSI drives", as in parallel SCSI? Getting hard and expensive to replace. "Xeon" - there is a huge difference between Xeon  generations, you should mention which socket is used. This sounds like equipment from the first half of the 2000s ... older redundant power supplies also tended to be inefficient and very wasteful with power.... I would honestly consider such gear hobbyist equipment and only commanding the corresponding price nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eBay and Craigslist are your best options unless you want to seek out local resources outside of Craigslist.

Comment: +1 for CL, you can actually try-before-you-buy. Too many sellers on eBay *way* overcharge on shipping.

Comment: so there is really not a place where big companies buy servers from that i was not aware of. i thought maybe there was a place that companies like google or some other large consumer of servers would buy wholesale or something and I could sell to them. Let me see if any more answers come up before I mark your answer as "answered" and thank you for answering!

Comment: @RandyMorris: The big [for varying values of "big"] companies I've worked with/for usually require vendor support contracts on hardware purchases. Not sure how many Grey Market dealers offer such support.

Comment: Companies'll be buying wholesale new, not untrusted used equipment. Donate to a non-profit who needs a much needed upgrade and is running on 10 year old junk.

Answer (score 4):

Southern CA might be better, but up here in the Great White North, it's hard to find other people to buy (or even to receive as donations) our old servers.  Every few years, we have a couple of old servers and a few old PCs, and I've never found a good way to dispose of them other than disposing of them.  The times I have been able to sell surplus equipment, I've used Craigslist.

Comment: I usually recycle old stuff using Free Geek Columbus in Columbus, OH and I have some other local sources as well.

Answer (score 3):

An IT hardware reseller would be a great option also, such as [www.core4solutions.com](http://www.core4solutions.com).  They have a buyback program that will pay you for your used IT hardware.

There is a link on the left of the homepage that you can click to submit info and they will get back to you.